# Create alert / message box in command line OSX app

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, alert

I'm trying to create a simple app that just opens an alert. So imagine this

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int result = SomeMagicAlertFunction("Hello World", "Yes", "No");
    printf("User picked: %d¥n", result);
}
```

I've found some info about `NSAlert` but all the examples are for full OSX Apps, the kind with an app package as in

```
+-MyApp.app
  |
  +-Contents
    |
    +-MacOS
      |
      +-MyApp
```

etc, but I just want an alert in a command line app. One file, not an app package. Is that possible in OSX in either C/C++ or Objective C? I saw something about `NSRunAlertPanel` but that's been removed in Yosemite and says to use `NSAlert`.

Answer (score 7):

Found an answer moments later

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

void SomeMagicAlertFunction(void) {
    NSAlert *alert = [[NSAlert alloc] init];
    [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];
    [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
    [alert setMessageText:@"Delete the record?"];
    [alert setInformativeText:@"Deleted records cannot be restored."];
    [alert setAlertStyle:NSWarningAlertStyle];

    if ([alert runModal] == NSAlertFirstButtonReturn) {
    }
    //[alert release];
}
```

Comment: FWIW, if you just want to show a message without keeping the program from finishing, you can use `CFUserNotificationDisplayNotice`.